# How to select multiple rows into a JSON string variable?

Tags: arrays, json, oracle, select, oracle19c

I have a REST API created using Oracle Resource Templates and I want to be able to execute a SELECT query using a PL/SQL block. I can return data as string, so I think one solution would be to store the query results as a JSON string and return it.

With an answer to this question, this other question will probably be solved [How can one return data from a Pl/SQL block in an Oracle REST API resource template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66836164/)

Example of what I tried to do; this code doesn't work:

```sql
declare
  items JSON_OBJECT_T;
begin
    select JSON_OBJECT(*) BULK COLLECT into items from my_table;
    :items := items;  -- :items will be returned by the API.
    -- I believe I would have to serialize the JSON_OBJECT_T to string somehow.
end;
```

**:items** must be assigned a valid JSON string, which must be an array of objects, where each object is a row.

Example of what I must have as answer from the API:

```json
"items": [
    {
      "name": "John",
      "age": "21",
      "sex": "m"
    },
    {
      "name": "Mike",
      "age": "22",
      "sex": "m"
    },
    {
      "name": "Susan",
      "age": "30",
      "sex": "f"
    }
]
```

Comment: Let's start with something simple. You say "Oracle 12.2" but you are attempting to use `json_object(*)`. The asterisk in `json_object()` is supported in Oracle 19, but it was not supported in Oracle 12.2. In 12.2 you need to know and reference individual column names. Is that a problem, or can you work with that?

Comment: @mathguy Sorry, I corrected the Oracle version, it's really 19c! If there's a solution that works in older versions even better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is something you can do in Oracle 12.2. In Oracle 19 it may be a bit simpler, using `json_object(*)`.

Using the standard `DEPT` table from the `SCOTT` schema for illustration:

```
declare
  items  json_object_t;
  result clob;
begin
  select json_object(
           key   'items'
           value json_arrayagg(
                   json_object(
                     key 'deptno' value deptno,
                     key 'dname'  value dname,
                     key 'loc'    value loc
                   )
                 ) format json
         ) 
  into   result
  from   scott.dept;
  items := json_object_t(result);
-- Check what is stored in items
  dbms_output.put_line('items.stringify = ' || chr(10) || items.stringify);
end;
/
```

I included a call to the `stringify` method to show the content of the `json_object_t` object. ApEx may prefer it in `json_object_t` data type - if all you need is a string, you don't need to construct that object, since `result` is already the string you need.

The result looks like this:

```
items.stringify = 
{"items":[{"deptno":10,"dname":"ACCOUNTING","loc":"NEW YORK"},{"deptno":20,"dname":"RESEARCH","loc":"DALLAS"},{"deptno":30,"dname":"SALES","loc":"CHICAGO"},{"deptno":40,"dname":"OPERATIONS","loc":"BOSTON"}]}


PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Note that the string is not pretty formatted - and it shouldn't be. That is something one would only do as the last step after receiving it, not from the "transmitting" end.

Comment: I'm getting an error with this: `PL/SQL: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected UDT got CHAR` while defining the `key 'deptno' value deptno` my code uses other table and column, but other than that it's the same.

Comment: Sorry - I demonstrated in my answer that the query works perfectly fine on a table like `scott.dept`. So, either your table is not "essentially the same", or your query is not a simple select on a simple table, or you modified the `json` functions. Let's start with the column. What is its data type? Use `describe [table_name]` to find out.

Comment: Also: In my example I selected directly from a table. If you need to select "from" the result of a query, that should work perfectly fine as an inline view in the `from` clause. It is possible that the optimizer is trying to simplify the query in some invalid way. A simple solution to that is to create the result set in a `with` clause, and use the `materialize` hint to prevent the optimizer from mixing the `json` generation process with the computation of your query output.

Comment: The column is `VARCHAR2`, my code is `declare
    result CLOB;
begin
   select json_object(
           key   'items'
           value json_arrayagg(
                   json_object(key 'setting_name' value setting_name)
                 ) format json
         ) 
  into   result
  from   system_options;
  :items := result;
end;`

Comment: @user5507535 - I assume you kept your declaration of the bind variable `input`? If so, that's the problem. You declared it as `json_object_t`. As you can see in my code, that is not necessary. I declared the variable as CLOB and selected directly into it - there is no need for another variable. In any case - in your code (whatever else you are doing), you have `input` declared as `json_object_t` and you are trying to assign a CLOB to it. Obviously that won't work.

Comment: No, instead of `input` I used `result` and it's a CLOB. `:items` is automatically created by the Oracle APEX. It says the error is in this line `json_object(key 'setting_name' value setting_name)`.

Comment: @user5507535 - OK, I understand now. I will edit the answer, showing both how to create the string and how to assign it to a `json_object_t` variable, using a constructor method.

Comment: However, it is odd that the error would be thrown at that line. And if you tried to assign a clob directly to a `json_object_t` the error should be different ("expression is of wrong type").